# Is historicity/unbiasedness of history books on-topic on History.se? How about recommendations?

Tags: discussion

As the title says: can I ask about historicity / unbiasedness of a history book on-topic?

Since I think this is also related

How about book/source recommendations for knowing more about a certain topic? (more than the respective Wikipedia articles, for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly legitimate to bring up a specific book or author and ask how well accepted their ideas are among historians. It would be refreshing for the question author to be aware that's the question they are asking. :-)

We are ... struggling with book recommendation questions. We get a lot of users who want them, and we have some users who'd like to answer them. However, such questions don't fit the StackExchange format well, and are typically not allowed on most stacks. I had a suggestion for a way to make it work [over on this question](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/book-recommendations-in-history-stack-exchange/2066#comment5492_2066), but it would be a fair bit of work, would require cooperation from the (often noobie) question asker, and didn't get much support.

Answer (score 2):

As a partial answer.  Book recommendations are off-topic:

- [Book recommendations in History Stack Exchange](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2065/book-recommendations-in-history-stack-exchange)
- [Closing of the question on Best Books for WWII](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/closing-of-the-question-on-best-books-for-wwii/122#122)

But some of us would like to change our FAQ to trial very limited types of source requests:

- [Proposal to permit reference questions on SE](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/proposal-to-permit-reference-questions-on-se)